# Sqlite: Can not select a row with a large integer id

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a row that has a pretty large value in the id column 350268180138164200. 
When I try to select it with

```
select * from my_table where id=350268180138164200
```

I get nothing, but when I insert a row with id=222 for instance I can select it with no problem.

```
select *, typeof(id) from my_table
```

shows that id's datatype is integer.

UPDATE:
I got rid of the trouble by altering my inserting code, that is what it looked like:

```
conn = lite.connect('my.sqlite')

with conn:
cur = conn.cursor()


    cur.execute("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID) "
                    "VALUES( :id)",
                    { 'id' : -here is smth of type = long- } )
    conn.commit()
```

Now I have altered it to look like (and select is working):

```
conn = lite.connect('my.sqlite')

with conn:
cur = conn.cursor()


    cur.execute("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID) "
                    "VALUES( CAST(:id AS INTERGER))",
                    { 'id' : -here is smth of type = long- } )
    conn.commit()
```

So I suspect python sqlite module (or sqlite lib itself) was doing some cast, which was aligned with my goals. Or I dunno.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Your Python code is not indented properly.

Answer (score 2):

Works here:

```
sqlite> create table t (id integer);
sqlite> insert into t values (350268180138164200);
sqlite> select * from t;
350268180138164200
sqlite> select * from t where id = 350268180138164200;
350268180138164200
sqlite> select *, typeof(id) from t where id = 350268180138164200;
350268180138164200|integer
```

Comment: Seems like I have a problem with inserting, I do it with python.